# Bring the dockable widgets to its default position in Qt

Tags: qt

I have several dockable widgets and the user can move it, to any place in the screen.
Also sometimes if the user drags out of the viewable area, there is no way to bring it back.

Is there any way to restore the widget position in Qt, to default position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the Widget positions in Registry. Have a default setting while installation and save the screen geometry. Eg:

```
   QSettings settings;
   settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
   settings.setValue("MRU", m_RecentFiles);
   settings.setValue("maximized", isMaximized());
   settings.setValue("minimized", isMinimized());
   if(!isMaximized())
   {
      settings.setValue("size", size());
   }

   QByteArray array = saveState();
   settings.setValue("state", array);

   QDesktopWidget desktopWidget;
   int nb = desktopWidget.numScreens();
   settings.setValue("screenNumber", nb);
   for(int i = 0; i < nb; ++i)
   {
      YString screenName = "screen" + YString::number(i);
      QRect rect = desktopWidget.screenGeometry(i);
      settings.setValue(screenName.data(), rect);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`QMainWindow::saveState()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#saveState) and [`QMainWindow::restoreState()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#restoreState) methods.

`saveState` returns a `QByteArray` containing the internal state of the main window, including the state and positions of the dock area's dock widgets. You can, for example, save this array in a file and restore the contents later by calling `restoreState()`.

If you want to have a default position, then position the dock widgets as you like to have it by default, retrieve the byte array (e.g. through some action which is only available in debug mode of your application), put the array hard coded into your source code or into some default configuration file, and then implement some kind of "reset" or "set defaults" action by simply passing this array to the `restoreState()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you just add a check into the [mouseMoveEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) that tests the QWidgets location and then decide if we need to move the widget back on screen.